# UI Headers Not Updating qt_ros

Tags: ros, gui, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a qt_ros package and integrated my QT application files into it. Everything has worked perfectly so far, but today when I added a new button to the .ui file the associated ui header file was not updated. Is this normal, or is there something wrong with my CMakeLists?

Note: This project started as a .pro project and uic ran fine on the .ui files then.

CMakeLists.txt
##############################################################################
# Rosbuild2
##############################################################################

```
if(ROSBUILD)
  include(rosbuild.cmake OPTIONAL)
  return()
endif()

##############################################################################
# CMake
##############################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)

##############################################################################
# Ros Initialisation
##############################################################################

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_genmsg()

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################

rosbuild_include(qt_build qt-ros)
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui QtWebkit QtNetwork) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/Google_Maps_CMAKE/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################

rosbuild_add_executable(Google_Maps_CMAKE ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(Google_Maps_CMAKE ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56281/ui-headers-not-updating-qt_ros/) by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-26**:
Can you update your question to add; `CMakeLists.txt`, `.ui` files and the command line you used? At least without those info it's hard to tell what's going on.

**Comment by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) on 2013-02-27**:
Sure. I will add them later tonight.

**Comment by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) on 2013-02-28**:
I just added the CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I figured out what was going on. When I started the project everything was in the same directory and I was using a .pro file. I needed to include the ui_form.h file in my form.cpp file to be able to access my buttons. When I would build the project this way, the ui_form.h file would be generated and stayed in the same directory as all of the other files.

I then decided to organize my project into include, src, ui, and resources folders. Since the ui_form.h file was a header file, I moved it to the include folder and updated my include statement to look in the include directory. Around this time, I switched to using CMake and discovered that the files were not updating when I changed the interface. I thought I would just delete the ui_form.h, since it was auto-generated. I did and a got a compiler error because my include statement pointed to the include directory.

I just realized that CMake puts the ui_form.h file in the build directory. I deleted the one I had in the include directory and changed my include statements in form.cpp to

```
#include "../build/ui_form.h"
```

instead of

```
#include ../include/ui_form.h
```

I am still not sure if this is the best way to do it since the build directory could be changed, but at least everything is working now.

---

Originally posted by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) with karma: 52 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [newToRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4221/newtoros/) on 2013-03-01**:
I am not yet able to accept my own answer. Feel free to accept it for me.